# How to fast forward folder of videos through multiple threads dynamically using moviePy in python?

Tags: python, windows, multithreading, moviepy

I have a folder of videos which I want to fast forward using multiple threads using moviePy. How do I Fetch the videos from the folder dynamically instead of giving their paths statically?  Here is my code :

1. from moviepy.editor import *

   import os

   from natsort import natsorted

   from threading import Thread

   def fast(path,thread_name):

   ```
   if os.path.splitext(path)[1] == '.mp4':

       #print(os.path.splitext(path))

       clip = (VideoFileClip(path).fx(vfx.speedx, 5))

       #print(clip)

       clip.to_videofile('G:/Ocsid Technologies/Video_1/'+thread_name + '.mp4', codec='libx264')
   ```

   t1 = Thread(target=fast, args=("G:/Ocsid
   Technologies/Video_1/sample1.mp4", 't1')).start()

t2 =Thread(target=fast, args=("G:/Ocsid
Technologies/Video_1/sample2.mp4", 't2')).start()

t3 =Thread(target=fast, args=("G:/Ocsid
Technologies/Video_1/sample3.mp4",'t3' )).start()

t4 =Thread(target=fast, args=("G:/Ocsid
Technologies/Video_1/sample4.mp4",'t4' )).start()

Answer (score 0):

You can enumerate files with `glob.glob()` and use `enumerate` to get a counter for your thread names.

```
import glob
# ...
for i, filename in enumerate(glob.glob("G:/Ocsid Technologies/Video_1/*.mp4"), 1):
    thread_name = f"t{i}"
    Thread(target=fast, args=(filename, thread_name)).start()
```

Comment: And now I want to concatinate these fast forwarded videos , How do I do it ?

Comment: That's a different question, but apparently https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/getting_started/compositing.html#stacking-and-concatenating-clips